# Java program to accept input between 2 numbers

Tags: java

This is a simple class exercise I'm working on. (I'm very new to programming so if this was a simple 'rookie' mistake I apologize for wasting your time.) I'm not going to lie: I'm finding it difficult to know *where* to insert certain pieces of code when programming.

```
import java.util.*;


public class SuperSaveRandallTWyngaardC {

     static Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       char newCust;
       char promo;
       int itemNr=0;
       int qty=0;
       int price=0;
       int totalPrice=0;
       int custTot=0;
       int noOfItems=0;
       int grandTot=0;
       int custCount=0;

      System.out.println(" "); 
      System.out.println("*******SuperSave - your friendly local store.....*******");
      System.out.println(" ");
      System.out.print("New customer? (Y/N)>> ");
      newCust=console.next().charAt(0);
      newCust=Character.toUpperCase(newCust);

      while((newCust!='Y')&&(newCust!='N'))
     {
      System.out.print("Invalid option, please re-enter (Y/N)>> ");
      newCust=console.next().charAt(0);
      newCust=Character.toUpperCase(newCust);
     }
     if (newCust == 'N')
    {
     System.out.println("*******NO SALES THE WHOLE DAY.....*******");
    }
     else if (newCust == 'Y')
    {
     System.out.print("Please enter the item number (1000 -> 5000 or zero for none)>> ");
     itemNr=console.nextInt();  

        while ((itemNr<1000)&&(itemNr>5000)||(itemNr!=0))
       {
        System.out.print("Invalid item number, please re-enter (1000 -> 5000 or zero to stop)>> ");
        itemNr=console.nextInt();
       }
        if (itemNr==0)
        {
         System.out.println("*******NO ITEMS WERE BOUGHT BY THIS CUSTOMER.....*******");
        }
         else if ((itemNr>1000)&&(itemNr<5000))
         {
          System.out.print("Enter quantity>> ");
          qty=console.nextInt();
         }
    }

    }    

}
```

Run the program. Sample output...

```
*******SuperSave - your friendly local store.....*******

New customer? (Y/N)>> y
Please enter the item number (1000 -> 5000 or zero for none)>> 1000
Invalid item number, please re-enter (1000 -> 5000 or zero to stop)>> 5000
Invalid item number, please re-enter (1000 -> 5000 or zero to stop)>> 999
Invalid item number, please re-enter (1000 -> 5000 or zero to stop)>> 5001
Invalid item number, please re-enter (1000 -> 5000 or zero to stop)>> 1234
Invalid item number, please re-enter (1000 -> 5000 or zero to stop)>> 4000
Invalid item number, please re-enter (1000 -> 5000 or zero to stop)>> 0
*******NO ITEMS WERE BOUGHT BY THIS CUSTOMER.....*******
```

The `while` loop says that any item number input is invalid (even when inside the specified range of 1000-5000)

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop condition is off.

Since the negatives seems to confuse, first write what is good:

```
(itemNr >= 1000 && itemNr <= 5000)  ||  itemNr == 0
```

I.e. must be between 1000 and 5000 (inclusive), **OR** must be 0.

Since most people can't get the precedence of `&&` vs `||` right, you should *always* use parenthesis to explicitly specify the precedence when mixing them, as I just did.

This makes reversing the expression easy, since you just reverse everything, and leave the parenthesis alone:

```
(itemNr < 1000 || itemNr > 5000)  &&  itemNr != 0     // correct #1
```

Compare that to what you had, and you'll see the problem:

```
(itemNr < 1000) && (itemNr > 5000) || (itemNr != 0)   // wrong
```

Since `> 5000` means that it definitely is `!= 0`, you can rearrange the expression like this, as others have shown:

```
(itemNr < 1000 && itemNr != 0) || itemNr > 5000       // correct #2
```

Technically, #2 performs better than #1, but that's a difference you will not *ever* notice. Personally, I find #2 less intuitive than #1, but that's a matter of opinion. They both get you want you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
(itemNr<1000)&&(itemNr>5000)||(itemNr!=0)
```

There is no itemNr that makes it true.
Consider -1, 1, 1001, 5001.

```
((itemNr<1000)&&(itemNr!=0))||(itemNr>5000)
```

You should try this.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it still did the same thing with "illegal start of expression and  ; expected"

Comment: Maybe there are some extra curly braces need to be removed. Check your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`(itemNr < 1000) && (itemNr > 5000)` Item number has to be smaller than 1000 *AND* greater than 5000 at the same time, that is not possible.

You are doing a similar check later with `(itemNr > 1000) && (itemNr < 5000)`.

It would be useful to make a function `isInRange(int)` that does this check. So you can use `!isInRange(itemNr)` (not in range) for the first check.

The second check is not needed, since the number will always be in range (or 0) after the while loop.

```
private static boolean isInRange(int i) {
    return ((i > 1000) && (i < 5000));
}

...

while(!isInRange(itemNr) && itemNr != 0) {
    ...
}

if (itemNr == 0) {
    ...
} else { // no need to check here
    ...
}
```

Comment: `while(!isInRange(itemNr) || itemNr != 0)` Still wrong. Thjs will be true for any number.

Answer (score 0):

To correct the check for valid inputs, 1000... 5000 and 0, update

`while ((itemNr<1000)&&(itemNr>5000)||(itemNr!=0))` 

to
`while ((itemNr < 1000 && itemNr != 0) || itemNr > 5000)`

If 1000 and 5000 are valid inputs, then you have to include them while getting the quantity.
`else if ((itemNr>1000)&&(itemNr<5000))`

to
`else if ((itemNr >= 1000) && (itemNr <= 5000))`

So the last block will look like

```
while ((itemNr < 1000 && itemNr != 0) || itemNr > 5000) {
    System.out.print("Invalid item nyumber, please re-enter (1000 -> 5000 or zero to stop)>> ");
    itemNr = console.nextInt();
}
if (itemNr == 0) {
    System.out.println("*******NO ITEMS WERE BOUGHT BY THIS CUSTOMER.....*******");
} else if ((itemNr >= 1000) && (itemNr <= 5000)) {
    System.out.print("Enter quantity>> ");
    qty = console.nextInt();
}
```